# Arrange the products according to their product type in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, listview

I would like to display products according to their product type in a listview, using groups, my first time working with this so im still unsure of what to do.

This is what i got this far:

```
String query = "Select * From Product";
        Prods = db.GetDataTable(query);

        String ProdTypeQuery = "Select * From ProductType";
        ProdType = db.GetDataTable(ProdTypeQuery);
        cmbProdType.DataSource = ProdType;
        cmbProdType.DisplayMember = "TypeDesc";
        cmbProdType.ValueMember = "TypeNo";
        cmbProdType.SelectedValue = 1;

        String queryReport = "Select * From Report";
        Report = db.GetDataTable(queryReport);

        foreach (DataRow dr in Prods.Rows)
        {
            ProdName.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            PrevCount.Add(int.Parse(dr[2].ToString()));
            ContainColumn(dr[1].ToString() + "Curr", Report);
            ContainColumn(dr[1].ToString() + "Prev", Report);
            //Check class here if possible
        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in ProdType.Rows)
        {
            listView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup(dr[1].ToString(), HorizontalAlignment.Left));
            foreach(DataRow drProd in Prods.Rows)
            {
                if(drProd[5].ToString()==dr[0].ToString())
                {
                    foreach(ListViewItem it in listView1.Items)
                    {
                        if(dr[1].ToString()==it.Name)
                        {
                            it.Group = listView1.Groups[dr[1].ToString()];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

These are my database tables:

Product:

[image: ProductTable]

ProductType:

[image: ProductTypeTable]

The "ProductType" column in the product table works with the "TypeNo" in the ProductType Table

Any help will be appreciated. My code does not work at all.

This is what it displays:

[image: Report]

Comment: Why not bind it to a DataGridView where you could sort by any column (just like in SSMS)?

Comment: Thing is, this is what i want to do, or try to do.

Comment: ListView won't really do it without working out a few other issues... It can't bind or sort in WinForms for example. ListBox will...